# $index is not defined error when i try to delete

Tags: php, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive

I'm building a project with angular and php. when I try to delete I have this error. the function gets all the information good and i can't understand why it doesn't work. can anyone please help?

```
$scope.delete = function( id)
        {

                  var deleteFile = $scope.files[id];
                  var txt;
                  var r=confirm("למחוק?");
                  if(r==true){
                  // var params = $.param({"id":deletingId});
                  $http.post('api/customers-tab/delete-priceOffer.php',{id:deleteFile})
                      .success(function(data){

                       var arr=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                        $scope.files = arr;
                         var arr2 = arr.split(",");
                          arr2.splice($index, 1);
                          $route.reload();



                  });

                }

        };
```

Html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in files track by $index  " >
        <td>{{ x.created}}</td>
        <td> {{ x.customer_id}} </td>
        <td> {{ x.full_name}} </td>
        <td> {{ x.city}} </td>
        <td> {{ x.phone}} </td>
        <td><a ng-click="delete($index)" value="Remove"  class="btn btn-primary btn- active">מחיקה</a></td>
```

PHP:

```
<?php



 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hamatkin");

  include_once 'file.php';
mysqli_query($connect,"SET character_set_client = utf8");
mysqli_query($connect,"SET character_set_connection = utf8");
mysqli_query($connect,"SET character_set_results = utf8");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
//$customer = new Customer();
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$x=$data->id;


 $id = $data->id;



$del = "DELETE FROM file WHERE id=".$data->id;



   mysqli_query($connect, $del);


 // echo "delete Ok".$x;
$newURL = "/hamatkin/#/allPriceOffers";
header('Location: '.$newURL);
?>
```

Comment: you passed `$index` to your function. in the function you use it as `id`.

Comment: Please put exactly you code portion so,

Comment: @AranS ok thanks! don't have the error anymore....now other error : Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: @VijayPatel I didn't understand what code

Comment: sorry ! my mistake for understanding of your question !!

Comment: Where does it originate from? sounds like a PHP problem

Comment: I will edit the code with the php @AranS

Comment: @AranS can you please have a look?

Comment: look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094276/catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-stdclass-could-not-be-converted-to-string

Comment: ok thanks i will  check

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$index` with `id`, You are passing `$index` value but taking in `id`

```
arr2.splice(id, 1);
```

Comment: ok thanks! don't have the error anymore....now other error : Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string